# How to delete the slash using REGEX

Tags: regular-expression

Hello I am trying to delete the `/`. I have problem looks like this , find all the files with the `.sh` extension in the current folder and delete the `./` before the name and the `.sh` after the name and this has to be within a file with the extension `.sh` which I named `find_sh.sh`.
I have tried `find . -name '*.sh' -print | sed 's/[.]//g' | sed 's/[/]//g'  | sed 's/.sh//g'`
but this also deletes `_` . What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have done it like this and it works `find . -name '*.sh' -print | sed 's/[.]//g' | sed 's/[/]//g' | sed 's/sh//'` and it works.

Comment: Note that you could simplify that to `find . -name '*.sh' | sed 's#\./##; s#\.sh$##`.

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern `.` match any character, not only literal dot. You need to escape it with backslash to prevent that. Your [other solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294186/80886) on the other hand removes all dots from the filenames, i.e. `a.b.sh` becomes `ab`. I propose the following alternative:

```
find . -name '*.sh' | sed 's,^./,,g' | sed 's/.sh$//'
```

Notice `^` which matches the beginning of the line and `$` which matches the end.

But even better use only one `sed` command:

```
find . -name '*.sh' | sed 's,^./\(.*\).sh$,\1,'
```

Comment: I have done it this way : find . -name '*.sh' -print | sed 's/.//' | sed 's/^[^_]*[/]//g' | sed 's/\.sh//'

Comment: @JohnnyOnPc create file: `touch my.shell.script.sh` and see the result of your command.